# Create Floating Menu With jQuery in NewForm.aspx

Tags: jquery, javascript, custom-form

**Part 1**. I'm attempting to add a floating DIV within a SharePoint form. The description within the DIV is critical for filling out the form correctly and must be viewable at all times. So, as the user scrolls down the form, the description remains visible. I have a rough working model using straight javascript and window.onscroll. Now, I would like to implement a good jQuery solution for this as I've done before with ordinary web pages. Here's my question:

- Where in SharePoint do I put jQuery files so that they can be referenced by any list form?

**Part 2**. The directions at this URL showed me how to

(1) create a new custom form (e.g. NewForm1.aspx), make changes and then

(2) associate the custom form with the New item.

http://www.referpages.com/reference/web/48-sharepoint/192-customform.html

All seems to ge well until I check the list again. That's when I notice that NewForm1.aspx is **NOT** associated with the list. List Properties show that NewForm.aspx is still associated with the list. This is indeed so because I can alter the URL for the page, replacing "NewForm" with "NewForm1" and see the difference. Note: I'm using SharePoint Designer an a SharePoint 2007 site. I'm modifying the site remotely.

- Why doesn't my attempt at list association work? I have all rights to the site.

Thanks in advance for any help with these issues,

Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1: You can put your jQuery files anywhere than can be referenced by URL. I usually recommend a Document Library at the root of the Site Collection, but you can also put them in the _layouts folder or use them from one of the CDNs out there, like Google or Microsoft. It all depends on what makes sense in your solution and is allowable by your governance.

Part2: As Matt (iOnline247) says, you have to choose the right content type in the Supporting Files dialog. It may be Document or Item or Event, etc., but it should never be Folder.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Matt! I now have my floating DIV working, courtesy of a jQuery plugin built by Logan Cai. -Arnold

Answer (score 1):

When you choose a different form, you have to make sure you select the proper content type for the form. SP defaults the content type to folder and will drive you nuts until someone tells you about it.  Happened to me too!!!

Comment: Thanks, Matt! It was driving me nuts, too.

-Arnold